# How to set HTML img src value using AR.ImageResource in ARchitectBrower.html Wikitude SDK for ios

Tags: javascript, html, ios, wikitude

I am editing the ARchitectBrowser.html provided by the Wikitude SDK iOS and I want to know how i can take an image set in AR.ImageResource

```
bubbleImage = new AR.ImageResource("http://graph.facebook.com/" + jsonObject[id].facebookId + "/picture",{onError:errorLoadingImage});
```

and place into an HTML img src attribute directly

```
<img id="imageFooter" src=""/>
```

in javascript I have a line like

```
document.getElementById("imageFooter").src = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + jsonObject[id].facebookId + "/picture";
```

but I want the image loaded into the AR.ImageResource to be set as the src attribute so I dont have to double up on HTTP requests.

Any help be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working at Wikitude on the SDK and we are always happy to hear about the developers needs. Unfortunately what you are trying to achieve is currently not supported. However you have a valid point and we will consider this for a next version. If there is a way you would prefere how this should work, please let us know here or at http://forum.wikitude.com/.